# Pass variables between different python process and ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Lately i have been trying to create XHR and i found out that Ajax is the only smooth way for achieving it. Apologies about my lack of understanding in Ajax, I just started it and i may not be doing everything properly.

Let's say there is a specific form like this:

```
<div style="margin: 0;float: left;width: 60px;height: 60px;cursor: pointer;text-decoration:none;display: block;padding: 0;">
    <form id="item_selection1" action="{% url 'Home:AccountPage' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="sendtrade" name="sendtrade1" type="submit" value="Send Offer">
    </form>
```

This is views.py:

```
...
if request.POST.get('sendtrade1'):
    ...
    openbox = "true"
    ...
```

And this is how i render response ( I know this is not Ajax compatible yet, assume that dict is already converted to json):

```
res = render(request, 'Home/account.html', {'other_keys': 'other_values', 'openbox': openbox})
return HttpResponse(res)
```

And i just normally open the div if openbox is "true":

```
if ("{{ openbox }}" == "true" ) {
    $("#someDiv").css("display", "block")
}
else if ( "{{ openbox }}" == "false" ) {
    $("#someDiv").css("display", "none")
}
```

**But**, Let's what if i execute certain nested function on the other process once post request is received:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
...
if request.POST.get('sendtrade1'):
    ...
    openbox = "true"
    ...
    def func():
        time.sleep(10)
        openbox = "false"
    proc = Process(target=func)
    proc.start()
    ...
...
```

How could i pass this to Ajax/Javascript without reloading the page? So when form is submitted, At first 10 seconds `#someDiv` is visible, But after 10 seconds it disappears again?

If this can't be done with Ajax, Then what is the another smooth alternative?

Comment: If you want to send messages from server to client, you need a socket connection. Take a look at [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the source, Would socket.io be safe for this? So i just need to create another thread and use socket.io on both Python and Javascript correct?

Comment: yes, pretty much. Here's a python version: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio

Comment: @ChrisG Apologies for being annoying, But i couldn't find any source about how could i listen to data from javascript, If you have any experience in python socket.io, Could you help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never used socket.io with a Python server. Did you look at the examples? Which python web framework are you using?

Comment: @ChrisG I am using Django, But examples are mostly dedicated to Flask framework...

Comment: Did you look at this? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-socketio/

Comment: @ChrisG No i haven't seen it, But this one does have Javascript examples! Thanks a lot!